# How does the Spring Boot Project generate release notes?

Tags: spring-boot

Here are the release notes for Spring Boot 2.3.1

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.3.1.RELEASE

I've searched everywhere in the Wiki, in Issues and in the code, but I can't find where these are being created.

Is this a manual process or automated in some way?

I'd love to take a similar approach in my projects but prefer not to do it manually if possible.

Does anyone know of any resources that describe how to generate release notes in this format with some level of automation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hello  if you look carefully in spring boot github repo, you will have this

```
spring-boot/ci/pipeline.yml
```

this is where they have their build/release workflow
and the file below is the script use to generate the github release note

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/ci/scripts/generate-changelog.sh